# How to disable all events of a label inside a DIV

Tags: jquery

Hi i am using this Code to unbind all the events attached to all lables inside a DIV.
But sadly it is not working.. Below is my code.

```
 $('#xxxxx-hidden label').die('click');
```

Please someone help me.

Comment: You almost answered your own question :)

Answer (score 6):

[die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/) only removes handlers that were added using [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Try [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) instead:

```
$('#xxxxx-hidden label').unbind('click');
```

If you really want to remove *all* the event handlers, you should call `unbind()` without arguments:

```
$('#xxxxx-hidden label').unbind();
```